# Is it possible to set up an Antminer S3 using a a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer, raspberry-pi

Hey everyone I am new to mining and just getting into it. I have done loads of research and haven't found the answer to my question. I have seen an Avalon 6 being run through a raspberry pi and I really like the idea of doing this. This being said I haven't seen the ability to do this with an Antminer S# series, and I am unsure why. I understand that it has its own controller and is more of a plug and play. I would like to run this through the raspberry pi though as it is more mobile and in general takes less space. Below is the video of the Avalon 6 being integrated: [Avalon 6 w/ raspberry pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL6MAJQE0aI)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

An Antminer S3 operates as a stand alone computer, so you need no controller. The device is configured and managed through a web browser interface, so you can configure it from any web browser.

The only downloaded tool from Bitmain for the Antimer that runs on a PC is their "IP address finder" app, and you can use any of hundreds of apps to discover the IP address of devices on your LAN, including [Fing](https://www.fing.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is talking about replacing the control board on the antminer s3 or s5 with a raspberry pi. You can use the raspberry pi with an antminer U3.